# Multicolor on UILabel in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, uilabel

I have a UILabel in which I need to display two different colored strings:
Below is my code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString: lbl_question.attributedText];

[text addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor colorWithRed:52.0f/255.0f green:104.0f/255.0f blue:165.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] range: NSMakeRange(0,[result integerValue]+1)];

[text addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor colorWithRed:75.0f/255.0f green:75.0f/255.0f blue:75.0f/255.0f alpha:2.0f] range: NSMakeRange([result integerValue]+1,[strq length])];
[lbl_question setAttributedText: text];
```

In iOS 6 it works fine but in ios 5 and  earlier versions the two strings just got ovelapped everytime.
also i want to get width according to text and font. increase height according to their text.

I am sure there has to be solution...Please help me out with this....

Comment: Attributed string support for UILabel etc. was only added in iOS 6. For earlier OSes you'll have to go with something like DTCoreText framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using NSMutableAttributedString. This will work in ***ios 6,ios 7 and ios 8*** also.

Note that NSMakeRange(startin gpoint counting from zero,number of character);

```
    NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"RedGreenBlue"];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,3)];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(3,5)];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(8,4)];   
    lable.attributedText=string;
```

Thanks

Comment: For all the attribute open the link  "https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004903-SW2"

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score -1):

From the NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Reference:

> NSForegroundColorAttributeName The value of this attribute is a
>   UIColor object. Use this attribute to specify the color of the text
>   during rendering. If you do not specify this attribute, the text is
>   rendered in black. Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

You need two labels, or use something like TTTAttributedLabel or DTCoreText.

Answer (score -1):

Try [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/). It's a subclass of `UILabel` that supports `NSAttributedStrings`, which would make it easy to have multiple colors, fonts, and styles in the same string.